# Is there any performance difference to put INNER JOINs before LEFT/RIGHT JOINS? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tend to always put `INNER JOINS` before any of my `LEFT/RIGHT JOINS`. I am not sure if this really has any speed difference.

So would this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.ID = Table1.ID
```

Execute faster/slower than:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.ID = Table1.ID
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

I tried to google the difference but could not find one. In my opinion I think that INNER JOIN filters out the rows and then LEFT join has to go through few rows.

Comment: Isn't there a , missing?

Comment: @frlan where? I dont see it. You can edit it

Comment: Nevermind ... was wrong. My fault. Sry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mysql optimizer looks at your code, your indexes etc and decides not only what to do first, but which (if any) keys are to be used. This is a complicated process and while you can try to influence it, you are most certainly less good equiped then the code ;D

So concluding: no, it does not matter.

Check out the optimizer part [of the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer.html)

Especially [this part about join order](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-joins-access-methods.html)

> A combination of a fixed order in which tables are joined and the corresponding table access methods for each table is called query execution plan (QEP). The goal of the query optimizer is to find an optimal QEP among all such possible plans.

You can check this out for yourself by adding `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and see what execution plan is performed by your database.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I check those links out. So I guess I will just go for consistency since all over my code I put INNER JOINS before any LEFT/RIGHT JOINS and will just keep doing that.

Comment: That's as good a strategy as any. I try to make sure the query "reads" right, so the real-world equivalent sounds good. Most of the time that means that 'optional' data (aka left join) goes last indeed. Do whatever works for you, but remember that `explain`. it is a vital tool in your toolkit for checking speed and if/how indexes are used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference due to the way of SQL is getting parsed and interprated.